# Changing slides order

Tags: image

Can please help me check if the code below is correct? I'm trying to reverse the order of the images display in the slides.

```
add_action( "init", "replace_gallery_init", 1000 );
function replace_gallery_init() {
remove_action( "adverts_tpl_single_top", "adverts_single_rslides" );
add_action( "adverts_tpl_single_top", "replace_gallery_with_lightbox" );
}
function replace_gallery_with_lightbox( $post_id ) {
$images = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post_id));
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-slides' );

if( empty( $images ) ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div class="rslides_container">
<ul id="slides1" class="rslides rslides1">
<?php $images = array(); 
$reversed = array_reverse($nimages); 
foreach ($reversed as $value) {echo "<li><img src='".$value."'    
alt=''></li>";} ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tmp_post->ID, 'large' ) ?>
<?php if(isset($image[0])): ?>
       <li>
        <img src="<?php esc_attr_e($image[0]) ?>" alt="">
        <?php if($tmp_post->post_excerpt || $tmp_post->post_content): ?>
        <p class="caption">
          <strong><?php esc_html_e($tmp_post->post_excerpt)?></strong>
                    <?php esc_html_e($tmp_post->post_content) ?>
                </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
}
```

I'm getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

Answer (score 1):

You have

`foreach ($reversed as $value) {echo "<li><img src='".$value."'

alt=''></li>";} ?>`

A little html and then you have this

`<?php endforeach; ?>`

You open a foreach loop, close it and then close a non existing foreach.
The syntax error says clearly that it is not expecting it.

Please read more carefully your error messages.